# Ubuntu 20.04 policy based symmetric routing with multiple interfaces in the same network

Tags: netplan

I have a pair of AWS VMs running Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm sharing an ENI between them.  Each host has an eth0 in 192.168.0.0/24 and the ENI is mounted as eth1 also in 192.168.0.0/24.

When I grab the ENI, I change the gateway so that traffic flows out eth1.  This destroys sessions connected to eth0 so I'm trying to find a pattern for symmetric routing.

Thanks!

Comment: I would normally build this with iproute2 or ip route iif commands but I'm not sure how to do this cleanly with just netplan.